# Proper framework for animating objects with lwjgl?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

My goal is to draw and animate 2D UI elements on the screen. The problem is, I'm not exactly sure how I can animate it without taking up a lot of space doing so.
This is what my method would look like to draw a red rectangle at 0, 0 with a width and height of 50

```
public void render() {
    Gui.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50, Color.red); // Drawing an object would look something like this
}
```

Now, what I would do is define a variable such as `rectanglePos = 0` and add that to the axis that I want to change. `drawRect(0 + rectanglePos, 0, 50, 50, Color.red);` Now when I want to animate the rectangle, I create a new Thread and animate it from there.

```
public void render() {
    Gui.drawRect(0 + rectanglePos, 0, 50, 50, Color.red); // Drawing an object would look something like this
}


public void animate() {
   Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
       float target = 50;

       for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            //ease(int start, int end, float time, EasingType type)
            rectanglePos = AnimationUtil.ease(0, target, 5, EasingType.CubicInOut);
       }
   });
   t.start();
}
```

This example here clearly is just bad. My question is, what is the best way to go about structuring this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, we can animate 2D UI elements on the screen with easing functions without Threads or other fancy stuff. Let's assume that we want the animation to move on the x-axis, starting at 10 and ending at 50. Assuming we know when to start and the duration, we can calculate when the animation ends.

Let's say `time` is equal to the current time, and `startTime` is equal to the time we start, and so on...
In a separate class, we need a few methods to help out. One method returns the progress of our animation. See [Easing Functions](https://easings.net/) for a list of standard easing functions. Another method converts this value into the start and end pixels.

The current progress would be equal to `(time - startTime) / duration`. This already gives us the value to put into our ease method. The ease method returns a value between `0.0` and `1.0`, so all we have to do is "convert" this into the pixels. The formula would be: `(end - start) * ease(alpha)`.

Here's the implementation of that concept. It's nothing perfect.

```
long startTime = 0L;

public void animate() {
    this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

// 10, 10 -> 50, 50
public void render() {
    // 1000 milliseconds = 1 Second
    drawRect(10 + Ease.toPixels(10, 50,Ease.getProgress(this.startTime, 1000L)), 10, ... etc);
}
```

Helping class:

```
// easeInOutCubic
public static float ease(float alpha) {
    return (float) (alpha < 0.5 ? 4 * alpha * alpha * alpha : 1 - Math.pow(-2 * alpha + 2, 3) / 2);
}

public static float getProgress(long startTime, float duration) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    float progress = (time - startTime) / duration;

    if (progress <= 0.0F) return 0.0F;
    if (progress >= 1.0F) return 1.0F;

    return progress;
}

public static int toPixels(float start, float end, float alpha) {
    return (int) ((end - start) * ease(alpha));
}
```